# In SAS: Specifying a reference level within PROC LOGISTIC

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I am running a `PROC LOGISTIC` statement, defining the reference level under the `class` as:

```
proc logistic data=data1 
class Var1 (param=ref ref=first);
model Var2=Var1 ;
run;
```

My contingency table looks like:

```
           Var1  
Var2     | 1      2   
---------------------- 
   0     | 1240   218
   1     | 924    224
```

Where I state the reference level of Var1 to be `first`, I mean it to be 1. This after all is the first level of variable `Var1`. The odds ratio that is given however, is 0.725. That would imply the second level, 2, is taken as reference group.

odds ratio given:

(924/1240)/(224/218)= 0.725

intended:

(224/218)/(924/1240)= 1.379

Is this a matter of definition of reference group, or am I not defining the level as intended?

Comment: Try using `ref='1'`. Does it give the same odds ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be happening, which does appear incorrect. Please contact SAS tech support.

```
data have;
input var1 var2 freq;
cards;
0 1 1240
1 1 924
0 2 218
1 2 224
;;;;

proc logistic data=have;
class var1 (param=ref ref='1');
model var2 = var1 / expb;
freq freq;
run;
```